# Why is gradient expressed as an integral like this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

I am wondering a few questions in regard to why my book says the following:

Consider the damped oscillator

$$x''+(x')^3+x=0$$ , we show it has no periodic solutions.

Say we have some energy function E, and suppose there was a periodic solution $x(t)$ of period T.

Consider $$E(x,x')=(1/2)(x^{2}+(x')^{2})$$

It says, after one cycle $\nabla E= 0$ around any closed orbit. Why is this true? I don't get how? I do know the theorem about conservative. So are we always able to assume that energy functions are conservative?
and
$$\nabla E= \int_{0}^{T} E^{\bullet} dt $$

also why is this true, and in general how is that result true?

where $E^{\bullet}$ is the derivative with respect to time.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747967/line-integral-equals-zero) might help in regards to your first question.

Comment: So are energy functions always assumed to be conservative?

Comment: $∇$ is used exclusively for the gradient. For differences, $\Delta$ is used, but be aware that the Laplace operator has the same symbol.

Comment: Can you explain how the definition of gradient gives us what you had, in the answer?

Comment: how are we allowd to assume conservative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read about [Lyapunov functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function).

But for the question, it is simply that if $x$ were periodic with period $T$, then $x(T)=x(0)$, $x(T+s)=x(s)$ and thus also $x'(T)=x'(0)$, so that of course also because of equal inputs into $E$
$$
E(T)=H(x'(T),x(T))=H(x(0),x'(0))=E(0).
$$

This would be true for any function $H$ of $x$ and $x'$, but with this $H(x,v)=v^2+x^2$ you know from $\dot E=∇H(x,v)·(\dot x,\dot v)^T$ and by the fundamental theorem of calculus that
$$
E(T)-E(0)=\int_0^T\dot E(t)dt=\int_0^T2x'(t)\,(x''(t)+x(t))dt=-2\int_0^Tx'(t)^4dt\le 0
$$
This can only be $0$ if $x'$ is the zero function, $x$ a constant which then also would have to be $0$.

---

### Approximate Amplitude Evolution

For small amplitudes the equation is almost a harmonic oscillator. Approximate this as $x(t)=r(t)\cos(t)$ with a slowly changing $r$. Then $E(t)\approx r(t)^2$ and
$$
r(t+\pi)^2-r(t)^2\approx-2r(t)^4\int_0^\pi\sin^4(s)\,ds
=-\frac{3\pi}4r(t)^4
$$
as $$8\sin^4(s)=2(1-\cos2s)^2=2-4\cos2s+(1+\cos4s).$$
The resulting recursion $$u_+=u-cu^2\approx u(1-cu_+),$$ $u=r(t)^2$, $u_+=r(t+\pi)^2$, $c=\frac{3\pi}4$, can in the indicated approximation be solved via 
$$\frac1{u_+}=\frac1u+c,$$ which extends iteratively to 
$$
r(t+k\pi)^{-2}=r(t)^{-2}+k\pi\frac{3}4
$$
By linear interpolation
$$
r(t)=\frac{r(0)}{\sqrt{1+\frac34 r(0)^2·t}}
$$

---

This gives the approximate solution 
$$
x(t)=\frac{r(0)\cos t}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3}4r(0)^2·t}}
$$
Already this very basic approximation gives visually convincing results, for instance in this visualization for $x(0)=a=0.5$, $x'(0)=0$:

[image: solution and first approximation]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda y,t: [ y[1], -y[0] - y[1]**3 ]
t = np.arange(0,60,0.05)   
a=0.5
sol = odeint(f, [ a, 0], t)

plt.plot(t, sol[:,0], 'b', label='exact')
plt.plot(t, a*np.cos(t)/np.sqrt(1+0.25*a*a*3*t), 'g', label='1.ord, 1. freq')
plt.xlabel('t'); plt.ylabel('x'); plt.grid(); plt.legend(loc='best'); plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand still how the gradient of E is equal to E(T)-E(0)

Comment: It is not. You must have some mis-communication somewhere. One could say $ΔE=E(T)-E(0)$ or with $E(t)=H(x(t),v(t))=H(y(t))$,$\dot E=∇H·\dot y$ which under integration gives $ΔE=\int_0^T∇H·\dot ydt$. In the Lyapunov formalism you also have $\dot H(y)=∇H·\dot y$ as abbreviation. That's all where nabla could occur as gradient.